# TERRAFORM GCP: Row-level policies in bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, terraform, policy, row-level-security

Is it possible to add a row-level policy to a table I'm creating with terraform on bigquery?
Or is it possible to specify it in the table schema?

bigquery's row level policy:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-row-level-security

I didn't find any ressource on this topic in terraform documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Although not the best solution, but technically it is possible to create it with a big query job:

```
resource "google_bigquery_job" "job" {
  job_id  = "rowaccesspolicy1"

  query {
    query = "CREATE OR REPLACE ROW ACCESS POLICY project ON project.dataset.table GRANT TO ('group:group@domain.com') FILTER USING (columnname = 'value')"
      
    create_disposition = ""
    write_disposition = ""
  }
}
```